# Application Layout Stylesheet Include Can't Find Image Asset Using Wicked PDF Using Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, wicked-pdf

My Rails 6 app is using webpack and yarn. I still use the asset pipeline for my sass stylesheets. I'm using a layout css stylsheet for my PDFs that I generate with Wicked PDF. I get the following error in production but not development (because of the config setting fallback to asset pipeline is false in production, according to best practice):

```
ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "%22images%2Fui-icons_555555_256x240.png%22" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

--

```
<!-- application.pdf.erb, used as my layout for PDFs -->
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application" %> <!-- this one is problematic -->
    <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application_pdf" %>
  </head>

<!-- application.scss , line of the error -->>
...
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap" // imported from node_modules, installed with yarn, using webpack
...
```

Why am I having trouble finding the ui-icons image asset? What am I doing fundamentally wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that some Jquery UI stylesheet imports were causing an issue. They were doing something funky with adding code that references images. Once I removed the JQuery UI imports, everything runs great.